# Request header field Authorization is not allowed

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have an Laravel based API on my Server. And I try to access this api from an AngularJS Frontend. Unfortunately this error shows up.

Where do I have to add the configuration to allow the Authorization Header?
I tried to find a solution but couldn't manage to solve it.

I tried to insert it in the `httpd.conf` and in the `.htaccess` of the Angular frontend but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: I use an Amazon Machine Image on AWS. I tried to add the Headers to the httpd.conf. But it still doesn't work. Is it possible that we have to add something to our JavaScript files accessing the api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quick Answer

If your server is using Apache, add the following snippet to your api's respective **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
</IfModule>
```

## More details

in the above snippet, we are asking Apache to allow `Authorization` header:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
```

you can add multiple `headers` in one line, like this, but keep in mind that it's advised to **only allow the headers required by your app**.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, X-Requested-With"
```

## Side Note

In a related note, people often need to allow cross-origin request (also known as Cross-Origin Resource Sharing or CORS). The following snippet allows cross requests from `https://example.com` origin:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
```

or you might use `"*"` to allow requests from all origins:
***Not Recommended***

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

## Wrap up

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # To allow headers
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"

    # to allow cross origin request from https://example.com
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nice it's exactly what I need